# Popup design change

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

I am trying to put another link (**Notes Methodologiques**) next to "**Zoom to**" in InfoWindowLite popup window but I don't know how I can have them in the same area.

What I have right now looks like this:

[image]

and the result I want looks like this:

[image]

here is the HTML I am using:

```
"<div class='esriPopup'>" +
"<div class='esriPopupWrapper'>" +
    "<div class='sizer'>" +
        "<div class='actionsPane'>" +
            "<div class='actionList'>" +
                "<a class='action zoomTo' href=http://ipaddress/notes.html target=_blank >" +
                 translator.T("Methodological Notes") + 
                 "</a>" +
             "</div>" +
         "</div>" +
     "</div>" +
 "<div>" +
 "</div>";
```

Comment: How was this done? where in the code was this done?
e.g. Web App Builder... which file was changed to change the Bottom link of 'Notes Methodologigues' whatever that word is.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. This looks like this should be a comment, which you will be able to do once you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you'll put the popup content inside the `sizer content` and if you'll rewrite the `actionList` like bellow, then everything will work as expected:

[image]